# В каком разрешении должен быть .wmv видео файл?

Tags: java, android

У меня был файл в формате `.wmv` и размер `480 * 800` я этот файл воспроизвожу в `VideoView` с помощью вот этого метода

```
private void playVideo(){
    videoView.setKeepScreenOn(true);

//      Here i set a path to video file
    String videoSource = "android.resource://com.example.android.camera2basic/" + R.raw.movie;
    videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(videoSource));
    videoView.setMediaController(null);

    videoView.setOnCompletionListener(myVideoViewCompletionListener);
    videoView.setOnPreparedListener(myVideoViewPreparedListener);
}
```

После того как файл был изменен(добавили продолжительность) он остался в том же формате `.wmv` но размер стал `808 * 1440` и теперь когда я воспроизвожу видео картинки нет, но видео идет...

Почитал и понял, что проблема может быть в большом разрешении...

И вот появился вопрос :

1. В каком разрешении должен быть этот файл, чтоб он воспроизводился на
   всех устройствах?
2. Или нужно это регулировать программно как то?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я просто конвертировал формат в `MP4` и все заработало...

Еще несколько севетов так сказать от старших разработчиков:

1. Хранить файл нужно в файловой системе телефона
2. Pазрешение его должно быть как можно меньшим, но достаточным...

Answer (score 0):

Разрешение неважно если в XML файле сделать так:

```
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Comment: И в чем разница? У меня сейчас android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"... Что поменяется?

Comment: Я сейчас тоже над видео плеером работаю я про эксперентировал и получилось что и так любое разрешение и формат влезают на экран, а с android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" некоторые видео искажаются

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то если поставить `match_parent` по высоте и ширине, то картинка может исказиться, поэтому лучше по высоте устанавливать `wrap_content` , верно?

Comment: Да так есть. Испытал на своей шкуре